# Using Test Deployment to deploy files from local bin/debug to Team Build Server

Tags: tfsbuild, azure-devops

I am facing issue in deploying items from local bin/debug folder to build server output binaries folder (using Microsoft Team Foundation Server). I have a resource file ABC.resx, which is converted to ABC.resources in post build event using the ResGen.exe. The ABC.resources get's created in local bin/debug folder, so I have added the following line in my Deployment settings -

`<Solution Directory>\FolderXYZ\bin\Debug\`

But I am getting the below warning when the build is created on build server and the tests are failing -

Test Run deployment issue: Failed to get the file for deployment item `FolderXYZ\bin\Debug\` specified by the test settings:

`System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\system32\FolderXYZ\bin\Debug\'.`

Is there someway I can add the resources file in Test Deployment Directory of Build Server?

Comment: Is C:\Windows\System32 your source directory on the server? I think that must be wrong. You can use the SourcesDirectory variable. Which version of TFS are you using? Are you using workflow build definitions?  Also is the build on the server running in "Debug" mode? If not the folder would be created in bin\Release